# Cocoa podspec file ignores dependency library

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I have the following podspec file for my iOS swift library:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "DialogView"
  s.version      = "0.1"
  s.summary      = "Highly customisable dialog (alert) view made in swift"
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/manGoweb/DialogView"
  s.screenshots  = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/manGoweb/DialogView/master/_orig/screenshot1.jpg"

  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENCE" }
  s.author       = { "Ondrej Rafaj" => "developer@mangoweb.cz" }
  s.social_media_url   = "http://twitter.com/rafiki270"
  s.platform     = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.1'
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/manGoweb/DialogView.git", :tag => "0.1" }
  s.source_files = "Classes/*"
  s.dependency "SnapKit", "~> 0.19.1"
  s.requires_arc = true
end
```

and whatever I do the file doesn't compile (the example project does in Xcode). When I do this:

```
pod spec lint ./DialogView.podspec
```

I get following errors:

```
Last login: Mon Feb 29 10:04:47 on console
-bash: rbenv: command not found
MacBook-Pro:DialogView pro$ pod spec lint ./DialogView.podspec

 -> DialogView (0.1)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  DialogView/Classes/DialogView.swift:64:9: error: value of type 'DialogView' has no member 'snp_makeConstraints'
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  DialogView/Classes/DialogView.swift:77:14: error: value of type 'UIView' has no member 'snp_makeConstraints'
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  DialogView/Classes/DialogView.swift:99:28: error: value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'snp_makeConstraints'
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  DialogView/Classes/DialogView.swift:112:30: error: value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'snp_makeConstraints'
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  DialogView/Classes/DialogView.swift:127:17: error: value of type 'DialogButton' has no member 'snp_makeConstraints'
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  DialogView/Classes/DialogView.swift:270:14: error: value of type 'DialogCurtainView' has no member 'snp_makeConstraints'

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 7 errors.

[!] Unable to read the license file `/private/var/folders/45/g7fzvx8j47q28sms19jm1kwh0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/DialogView/LICENCE` for the spec `DialogView (0.1)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `/private/var/folders/45/g7fzvx8j47q28sms19jm1kwh0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/DialogView/LICENCE` for the spec `DialogView (0.1)`
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had a quick look, but it seems like the way you've structured you project is causing some problems. I'd recommend using the structure recommended by CocoaPods [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html). It involves having an example project that use a local file reference to the under development pod.

Comment: Ah, I see ... thank you very much, I'll let you know if this works so you can post it as an answer :)

Comment: Great, feel free to ask anything or just push the code and I'll have a look.